# Choosing the correct forumla in a sequence of bernouli trials( combinatorial method)

Tags: probability

I have some questions regarding  choosing  the right method for computing the  probabilities for the following  problem.

What I'd like is some advice  on how could I actually  determin the right way for a specific problem.

E.g.:

```
The probability of a car battery not to start is 0.03 
( => q= 0.03 and p = 0.97)
a)..
b) The battery starts on the first at least 25 consecutive atempts.
```

What method should be used for b) ? I am considering Hypergeometric Model, but I'm not sure how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume *independence*, the probability we succeed in starting the car $25$ times in a row is $(0.97)^{25}$. This is a consequence of the multiplication principle for probabilities.

If we *really* want to use a named distribution, the appropriate one is the binomial distribution. The probability of $25$ successes in $25$ trials is  $\binom{25}{25}(0.97)^{25}(0.03)^0$. But that is an unnecessarily complicated view of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the  explanation :)

Comment: You are welcome. Hypergeometric is different, it comes from sampling without replacement.